# Is there any way to uninstall DirectX 12 from Windows 10 and install DirectX 11

Tags: directx

I have Intel HD 3000 graphics which are not compatible with DirectX 12. I am having issues in some games so I thought maybe I could install DirectX 11 on Windows 10 which is compatible with my GPU. Is this method possible in any way?

Comment: You need to be sure Direct X 11 will solve your problem because Direct X is tied up with your graphics adapter. There are some possibilities for you in this article:  https://windowsreport.com/directx-errors-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

DirectX12 is in theory backward compatible and Windows 10 includes
DirectX 11.3.
Nevertheless, if the game in question is badly programmed and insists on DirectX11, then you may try one of the workarounds below.

**Set game compatibility mode**

Running the game program in Windows 7 mode should force it to use
(or emulate) DirectX 11, since DirectX 12 was only introduced in Windows 10.

- Find the game's `.exe` file
- Right-click and select Properties
- Go to the Compatibility tab
- Check "Run this program in compatibility mode for:"
- In the drop-down list choose "Windows 7"
- Click OK and try the game,

**Set game DirectX level**

Find the program `DXCpl.exe`. On my computer it is found in
`C:\Windows\System32\DXCpl.exe` for 64-bit and
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DXCpl.exe` for 32-bit,
but may require some installation (let me know if you can't find it).

Start the program, add the game's `.exe` and set its DirectX level:

[image]

Comment: One cannot download and install DirectX 11 on Windows 10.

Comment: Just to clarify, the article talks about installing DirectX 9 not DirectX 10, DirectX 11, or DirectX 12.  Unfortunately, I don’t see this answer, as being salvageable.

Comment: @Ramhound: Bloody hell, Microsoft now prevents installing DirectX 11 on Windows 10. No matter, will find a solution.

Comment: Microsoft has always prevented DirectX 11 from being installed, there was never an installer, so it was never possible

Comment: @Ramhound: I never had a problem with installing a game's DirectX on Windows, but haven't done this now for a couple of years.

Comment: You installed DirectX 9 not any recent version of DirectX since Windows 8+ was released.  DirectX 10 and DirectX 11 was installed and only (originally) supported by Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 respectfully.  While DirectX 12 is a feature that is only supported by Windows 10 although many of it's features were ultimately backported to DirectX 11 in recent years (due to the 30-40% market share of Windows 7 at the time).

Comment: I did the aforementioned but it did not work. To specify, I am trying to run fortnite on my 7 yr old potato laptop, but whenever I launch it it generates the error "DX11 feature level 10.0 required to run the engine. I checked and I do have feature level 10.0 in DX12.

Comment: I found a version of DirectX 11 that can be installed on Windows 10 (I tested). Download from Microsoft the [DirectX Software Development Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) and install it. By default it will install into folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)`, where the sub-folder `Developer Runtime` contains the DLLs. If the game doesn't find them, ensure this is in the PATH, or even copy them into the game's folder. It advertises itself as "Direct3D 10.1 Extensions Debug" so is a development version, but might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this method possible in any way?

It is impossible to install DirectX 11 on any version of Windows.  DirectX 11 and DirectX 12 are built-into compatible versions of Windows.

> I have Intel HD 3000 graphics which are not compatible with DirectX 12. I am having issues in some games so I thought maybe I could install DirectX 11 on Windows 10 which is compatible with my GPU.

If your hardware supported DirectX 11 and the software supported DirectX 11 you would not have a problem running the software.

Here is the simple fact, your hardware is extremely dated, and doesn’t meet the minimum requirements to run it.